# Use of 'went' as a noun

Tags: word-usage, etymology, nouns, past-tense, neologisms

I have come across its use as a proper noun in an 1895 deed:

> "...all that one piece of pasture lying at Whatling Went."

So I wondered if there is any evidence for the the use of *'went'* as a common noun, as a back-formation from the verb. Otherwise, how would anyone have thought to use it in this name?

Intuitively it seems to have the meaning of a strip of land or track along which you go.

I can think of another jokingly inventive use of 'went' as a noun, as in
"These days he has plenty of got up and went." But that's different.

Comment: It reads like a place name; a double-worded proper noun.

Comment: Scanning dictionaries I get a vague hint that "went", in old British, can mean a path or road.  I know that "Went" is used in some place names in Britain.

Comment: Wiktionary lists the obsolete noun usage.

Comment: Probably this, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watling_Street as Hot Licks says.

Comment: No, Whatling is a local surname. The deeds relate to Suffolk, nowhere near Watling Street.

Comment: @Decapitated Soul: why remove the tag [is-it-a-word]? I thought the tag definition was the most apt of all: "Questions about the perceived legitimacy of would-be words".

Comment: @Decapitated Soul: With the benefit of hindsight of the answer, we now know 'went' is already a word. However, the question was asking whether it is a word. I didn't want to roll-back, 'cos I'm a new contributor, so I'm learning customary procedure.

Comment: @Decapitated Soul: Understood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, *went* is an obsolete English noun for a *road*, *way*, or *course*. Here's the Oxford English Dictionary, "[went, n.](https://oed.com/view/Entry/227819)":

> 1. a. A course, path, way, or passage. *Obsolete exc. dialect.*

The word originates around the fourteenth century in Middle English, and is possibly connected to the verb *wenden*, to walk or travel (Middle English Dictionary, "[went(e, n.](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED52214/track?counter=1&search_id=4190142)"). Back to the OED, this excerpt from Chaucer shows both the verb *went* and the noun *went* in the same line, indicating how they function differently:

> c1384   G. Chaucer Hous of Fame 182   In a forest, as they *wente*, At a turninge of a *wente*.

The latest usage cited is from about 1896, around the same time the deed you cite was written:

> a1896   C. W. Bardsley Dict. Surnames (1901) 802   There are one or two wents, still so called, in my late parish [Ulverston].

Incidentally, the place name usage seems limited to referring to roads or courses. For instance, the village name and surname *Wentworth* comes from the Old English *wintra* (winter) and *worð* (enclosure) ([Ancestry](https://www.ancestry.com/name-origin?surname=wentworth)).